# How to implement Ant-design navbar for react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobile-application, antd-mobile

I'm using `antd-mobile-rn` for my react native app. However, I cannot find `navbar` in this library. Only find `navbar` component in `antd-mobile` library , but I can't use it in my react native app. Anyone has experience about this issue? Need to use `navbar` of `other library`?

Answer (score 0):

I am using antd-mobile-rn only. For, navigation I used [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html).